# Subclass a composite GWT widget

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwtbootstrap3

I would like to subclass (extend) the [Modal widget from GWTBootstrap3](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#modals) to create a custom modal widget that can be reused within my app. I don't know how to do this when using UiBinder. I can do it only in java code by creating a ModalHeader, a ModalBody and a ModalFooter and adding them using add(Widget) method.

But how can I do the same using UiBinder for my subclass?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom widget in UiBinder code. Is that what you are up to? Just import the package where your custom widget is into a separate namespace. Say the widget *WeatherReport* is in the package *com.my.app.widgets* and the namespace you want to use is *my*, the import looks like this:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    xmlns:my="urn:import:com.my.app.widgets">
```

Now you can add *WeatherReport* objects in UiBinder code like this:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <my:WeatherReport ui:field="weather" />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

See the [official GWT documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_a_widget) for more information.

Using *ModalHeader*, *ModalBody* and so on in UiBinder works the same way. Import the respective package and use the components, here is a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
        xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
        xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui">
        <b:ModalBody>
                <b:Row>
                        <b:Column size="MD_12">
                                <b:Input ui:field="passwordInput" type="PASSWORD" />
                        </b:Column>
                </b:Row>
                <b:ModalFooter">
                        <b:Button ui:field="saveButton" text="Save" type="PRIMARY" />
                        <b:Button ui:field="cancelButton" text="Cancel" />
                </b:ModalFooter>
        </b:ModalBody>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: Yes, this is on the right track for what I hope to achieve. But, how would the java version of WheaterReport look, would it extend Modal? Also,  <b:ModalFooter> shouldn't  be inside of <b:ModalBody>, right?

Comment: The Java part of the _WeatherReport_ component looks like this:

`public class WeatherReport extends ModalBody {
        private static WeatherReportUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
                        .create(WeatherReportUiBinder.class);
        interface WeatherReportUiBinder extends
                        UiBinder<Widget, WeatherReport> {
        }

        public WeatherReport() {
                add(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }
}`

Comment: And this is how I use it with _Modal_ widgets:

`Modal modal = new Modal();
modal.setClosable(true);

WeatherReport widget = new WeatherReport();
modal.add(widget);
modal.show();`

If you find a more elegant integration, I am all ears :-)